# Probability in Dice

Tags: probability, permutations

What is the meaning of unbiased diced?

> Two unbiased dice are thrown. Find the probability that neither
>   doublet nor a total of 10 will appear.

to solve this problem I have tried to eliminate :$1+1,\ \  6+4, \ \ 5+5$
Now how to find the possible out come and total outcome?

Comment: Unbiased: every result is equally as likely.

Comment: Unbiased means each number has probability $\frac{1}{6}$ of showing up on any toss.

Comment: Then the probability will be $\frac{33}{36}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that one die is red and the other green, Christmas dice. Record the result of the experiment as an ordered pair $(x,y)$, where $x$ is the number on the red, and $y$ is the number on the green.

Since the dice are fair, all outcomes on red are equally likely, as are all outcomes on green. Since the dice do not influence each other, all $36$ outcomes are **equally likely**.

We will be happy if we get  neither a "doublet" nor a sum of $10$. It is a little easier to count the outcomes that will make us unhappy.

Make a list of all outcomes that have a "doublet." These are $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, and so on, $6$ of them.

List all outcomes that lead to sum $10$. These are $(4,6)$, $(5,5)$, and $(6,4)$, $3$ of them.

But note that $(5,5)$ is in both lists. So the number of **bad** outcomes is $8$.

The number of **favourable** outcomes is therefore $28$.

Thus the required probability is  $\dfrac{28}{36}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 
If considered as a result the sum of the two dice, you can make a $6\times 6$ arrangement, to find all possible outcomes.

Comment: Then the probability will be $\frac{33}{36}$?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I did it the same way Andre` did it. Since you have 6*6=36 possible pairs.
So you count the number of doubles {1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6}, which of we have 6.
Now count the number of pairs that sum to 10. {5,5},{4,6} but lets not forget the flip {6,4}, so that is a total of 3.

Now the question asks how many are NOT (Double or 10)
Let $D$=number of doubles. Let $B$=be the number of 10 pairs.
So we want $\neg(D\cup B)=T-(D\cup B)=36-(D+B-D\cap B)=36-(6+3-1)=28 $
Now divide this by the total 36. To get $28/36$